# Help identifying Evil Dead like movie

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

I watched a movie about fifteen to twenty years ago (I want to say it was made in the eighties or nineties) that is a lot like Evil Dead. It's one of the most bizarre horror movies I've ever seen, but I can't seem to find it on google.

The closest film I've found that could be it is called "Night of the Demons," but I'm not sure that is it. There a few scenes, however, that could help:

- A possessed woman in a white gown gets run into by a car into a tree over and over while she laughs.
- Someone is getting into their car and a possessed dude grabs their feet. I think this was at a gas station or convenience store.

Unfortunately, that's all I recall. I didn't see a resemblance of any of these scenes in "Night of the Demons," though.

There is another scene I remember, but I'm not sure if it's related to the same film.

- Black woman confronts bald white guy who claims he is the devil and they fall in love or something? I do remember they kiss and I think the black woman ends up killing him. When she does, I remember his blood being green? Strange, I know, but this is what I remember.

Infinite kudos to the person who can identify this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe a long shot, but could it be the [Tales from the Crypt: Demon Knight](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114608/?ref_=ttmi_tt)?

My reasons for thinking this:

1. Story takes place largely in a hotel/Inn, very Evil Dead feeling.
2. Made in 1995, fits time line.
3. Stars white bald guy (Billy Zane) as the ultimate evil (I don't remember if he's just a demon or the devil).
4. ALSO stars Jada Pinket Smith.
5. They *do not* fall in love, but she fills her mouth with holy blood and kisses him at the end, thereby dispatching him.
6. I believe their is green blood.

This guy look familiar?

[image]

Here's a [plot summary](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114608/plotsummary?ref_=tt_stry_pl):

> A man called Frank Brayker is driving a car through a desert road chased by another car. They crash and Brayker flees from the spot. He unsuccessfully tries to heist a car and stumbles upon the alcoholic Uncle Willy. Then he asks for a place to stay and Willy indicates a nearby bed and breakfast in an abandoned church. Brayker goes with Willy to the inn where he checks in with the owner Irene. He is introduced to the guests: the whore Cordelia; the postal clerk Wally Enfield and the maid Jeryline. Meanwhile, Sheriff Tupper and Deputy Bob Martel finds a man called The Collector near the accident that tells that Brayker is a thief that has stolen a key-like relic from him. When the crook Roach, he tells about the attempt of theft of a car, the suspicious Irene calls the Sheriff that comes with his Deputy and The Collector that tries to retrieve the relic. When the Sheriff decides to take Brayker and The Collector to the police station since both cars were stolen, The Collector kills him with a powerful punch. However Brayker uses the relic to expel The Collector to outside and he uses his blood on the soil to create demons. However Brayker uses blood from the relic to protect the inn. The Collector is unable to get in the place and uses his power to tempt each person inside the inn. Who will win the battle between good and evil?

Comment: OMG that really is it! I had to skip to the ending to make sure, but, yeah, Jada and Zane both had very memorable performances in that scene. I haven't had time yet to see if the other scenes I described are in it, but for now, I'll just mark this as solved and check out other Tales from the Crypt features. Thank you!